# Difference between Xcode build settings and Scheme environment variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, configuration

What is the difference between setting environment variables in Build Stting>User Defined vs  Edit Scheme>Arguments>Environment Variables?
I have a Debug Staging Configuration and using it in a scheme.
Would like to use these variables in info.plist and inside my Swift code.
(setting URL endpoints, api keys etc.) to switch between environments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Build Setting` are used when building. The `Scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment Variables` are used at run time.

If you want to use variables in your .plist file, you'll need to have them available when building, so `Build Settings` is where you'll define them.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely explains it.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the environment variables by:

Swift:

```
  let environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    if let environmentValueString = environment["VARIABLE_NAME"] {
        environmentValue.text = environmentValueString
    }
```

Objective C:

```
    NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    if (environment[@"server_url"]) {
// Set server url with the value in the         environment
    } else {
       // Set the default one
    }
```